# Thread-safe Tree

Tags: java, multithreading

Is there a thread-safe implementation of a tree in Java? I have found a bit of information that recommends using synchronized() around the add and remove methods, but I interested in seeing if there is anything built into Java.

**Edit:** I am trying to use an [Octree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree).  Just learning as I go, but I am using this project to learn both multi-threading and spatial indexing so there are lots of new topics for me here. If anyone has some particularly good reference material please do share.

Comment: …as opposted to using java.util.concurrent.* containers as the basis? What would make a "tree" not thread-safe?

Comment: What kind of tree, and for what purpose? A B-tree, red-black tree, etc?

Comment: @BRPocock: the same thing that would make any other data structure non-thread-safe: non-synchronized non-atomic concurrent updates to its state.

Comment: use java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet for better performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation for TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html):

```
SortedMap m = Collections.synchronizedSortedMap(new TreeMap(...));
```

Note that this only makes each call synchronized. In many cases this is the wrong granularity for an application and you are better off synchronizing at a higher level. See the [docs for synchronizedSortedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedSortedMap%28java.util.SortedMap%29).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Collections.synchronizedSet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedSet%28java.util.Set%29) or `synchronizedMap()` to add the synchronization around individual methods, but thread safety isn't really a property of a data structue but of an application. The wrapper will not be sufficient if you iterate over the tree, or do series of operations that need to be atomic.

Answer (score 0):

A [java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) might be of interest.  This is overkill for most uses, but if you need fine-grained synchronization there's nothing like it.  And overkill beats underkill.  Of course, it's not a tree, but does the same job.  I do not believe you can get low-level synchronization in a real tree.

Comment: But there is an equivalent java.util.concurrent.concurrentSkipListSet also available. Which is perfect for this condition. More effective than using SyncronizedSet().